# Predict and plot interaction term without single effect

Tags: r, glm, predict, interaction

I have a problem in plotting an interaction and in using predict function. This is my final model:

```
mymodel <- glm(y ~ SITE + TREAT*HET,  family= quasibinomial, data = PRESU)
```

I want to plot the interaction between `Treat` (categorical, 2 levels) and `Het` (continuous). Following Crawley chapter 16 (more or less, but there is no other variable in the example),  I tried  this  code:

```
x <-seq(0,1,length=100)
v <- rep("treat1", length(x))
y <- predict(mymodel, list(TREAT=factor(v),HET=x), type="response")
plot(HET[TREAT=="treat1"], fitted(mymodel)[TREAT=="treat1"],col="black")
lines(x,y,col="Black",lwd=1.5,lty=3)
t <- rep("treat2", length(x))
s <- predict(mymodel, list(TREAT=factor(t),HET=x), type="response")
points(HET[TREAT=="treat2"],fitted(mymodel)[TREAT=="treat2"],col="red")
lines(x,s,col="red",lwd=1.5)
```

I got this output at the predict

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'SITE' not found.

I cannot understand how I can plot my interaction from the model. If I remove `SITE` the code works, but I want to keep it in the final model. I hope that I explained clearly. Thank you for who can help .

Dataset:

```
SITE  TREAT1   HET     Tot   Prey
1     treat1   0.3     30    9
1     treat2   0.5     30    16
2     treat1   0.8     30    19
2     treat2   0.76    30    25
3     treat2   0.97    30    1
3     treat1   0.75    30    23
4     treat1   0.67    30    18
4     treat2   0.89    30    29
```

I have more replicates for each sites but let´s say that is something similar to my dataset. The response variable is y = (`prey`, `tot-prey`)

Comment: Would you please add a link to your data (PRESU) or include a reproducible data set?

Comment: Predict takes a dataframe for the values which you would like to predict.  Your function call contains a list.  Try:  predict(mymodel, data.frame( TREAT = factor(t), HET = x), type="response")

Comment: You need to make a  new data argument that has one level of SITE and values from seq() of HET across its range crossed with the two values of TREAT. Then plot  the results. IMHO Crawley's not the best way to learn R or statistics.

Comment: Hej, thank you everyone. I edited the question including a similar dataset. As suggested I tried using dataset instead of list but still it appear the serror message.  Also, I don t get how to create the new data as suggested by last answer. SOrry but I am not so advanced in R ( I am working on this). Thank you

Comment: I also forgot ot write that SITE has 7 levels.